# Is there a way to get the File Sharing Link of files in Google Drive?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

Is there a way to get the "file sharing link" of all files in Google Drive using python?

Comment: Can you provide the sample value of `file sharing link` you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume by file share link you mean that if you share a file though google drive web app you can select the copy link and get a link that can be shared with anyone giving them access to view the file in question

[image]

No it is not possible to create this link via the Google drive api in any programming language.

The best you could do would be to set the file to public and then get the download link or the web link via the google drive api for the file.   This is works but is not optimal for a lot of use cases.